# django - must have at least one form field filled in

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms

I am learning to use Django 1.4 (I will be upgrading as soon as 1.7 is released).

I have a test form in which I have marked all the fields as required=False, but I need to have the user enter at least one field on the form. It does not matter which field is entered, so long as at least one entry is made.

I do have a working solution, but I think that this could be done better, so I am hoping that some one with a better understanding of django can show me a better solution.

Here is my model code:

```
....
nationality_visa_country_of_birth = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
nationality_visa_citizenship = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
nationality_visa_residency = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
nationality_visa_work_visa = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
nationality_visa_study_visa = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
nationality_visa_specialist_visa = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
nationality_visa_other_visa = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
nationality_visa_current_valid_passport_display_type = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
nationality_visa_multiple_passports = models.BooleanField(default=False)
nationality_visa_passport_nationality = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
nationality_visa_timestamp_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
nationality_visa_timestamp_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
....
```

Here is my form code:

```
nationality_visa_country_of_birth = forms.CharField(label=_('Country of Birth'), max_length=250, required=False)
nationality_visa_citizenship = forms.CharField(label=_('Citizenship'), max_length=250, required=False)
nationality_visa_residency = forms.CharField( label=_('Residency'), max_length=250, required=False)
nationality_visa_work_visa = forms.CharField( label=_('Work Visa'), max_length=250, required=False)
nationality_visa_study_visa = forms.CharField( label=_('Student Visa'),max_length=250, required=False)
nationality_visa_specialist_visa = forms.CharField(label=_('Specialist Visa'), max_length=250, required=False)
nationality_visa_other_visa = forms.CharField(label=_('Other Visa'), max_length=250, required=False)
nationality_visa_current_valid_passport_display_type = forms.TypedChoiceField(coerce=int, label=_('Current Valid Passport'), choices=[(x, x) for x in range(0, 3)], required=False)
nationality_visa_multiple_passports = forms.BooleanField( label=_('Multiple Passports'), required=False, help_text=_("Select this option if you're going to enter multiple passport details into the field below."))
nationality_visa_passport_nationality = forms.CharField( label=_('Nationality of Passport(s)'), max_length=250, required=False)
```

Here is the validation data  on the forms.py that does ask the user to enter at least one field:

```
def clean(self):

    cd_nvdf = super(NationalityVisaDetailsForm, self).clean()

    if 'nationality_visa_country_of_birth' in cd_nvdf and len(cd_nvdf['nationality_visa_country_of_birth'].strip()) == 0:
        if 'nationality_visa_citizenship' in cd_nvdf and len(cd_nvdf['nationality_visa_citizenship'].strip()) == 0:
            if 'nationality_visa_residency' in cd_nvdf and len(cd_nvdf['nationality_visa_residency'].strip()) == 0:
                if 'nationality_visa_work_visa' in cd_nvdf and len(cd_nvdf['nationality_visa_work_visa'].strip()) == 0:
                    if 'nationality_visa_study_visa' in cd_nvdf and len(cd_nvdf['nationality_visa_study_visa'].strip()) == 0:
                        if 'nationality_visa_specialist_visa' in cd_nvdf and len(cd_nvdf['nationality_visa_specialist_visa'].strip()) == 0:
                            if 'nationality_visa_other_visa' in cd_nvdf and len(cd_nvdf['nationality_visa_other_visa'].strip()) == 0:
                                if 'nationality_visa_current_valid_passport_display_type' in cd_nvdf and cd_nvdf['nationality_visa_current_valid_passport_display_type'] == 0:
                                    if 'nationality_visa_passport_nationality' in cd_nvdf and len(cd_nvdf['nationality_visa_passport_nationality'].strip()) == 0:

                                        self._errors['nationality_visa_country_of_birth'] = self.error_class([_("You must enter at least one Nationality & Visa Detail.")])
                                        self._errors['nationality_visa_citizenship'] = self.error_class([_(" ")])
                                        self._errors['nationality_visa_residency'] = self.error_class([_(" ")])
                                        self._errors['nationality_visa_work_visa'] = self.error_class([_(" ")])
                                        self._errors['nationality_visa_study_visa'] = self.error_class([_(" ")])
                                        self._errors['nationality_visa_specialist_visa'] = self.error_class([_(" ")])
                                        self._errors['nationality_visa_other_visa'] = self.error_class([_(" ")])
                                        self._errors['nationality_visa_current_valid_passport_display_type'] = self.error_class([_(" ")])
                                        self._errors['nationality_visa_passport_nationality'] = self.error_class([_(" ")])

                                        del self.cleaned_data['nationality_visa_country_of_birth']
                                        del self.cleaned_data['nationality_visa_citizenship']
                                        del self.cleaned_data['nationality_visa_residency']
                                        del self.cleaned_data['nationality_visa_work_visa']
                                        del self.cleaned_data['nationality_visa_study_visa']
                                        del self.cleaned_data['nationality_visa_specialist_visa']
                                        del self.cleaned_data['nationality_visa_other_visa']
                                        del self.cleaned_data['nationality_visa_current_valid_passport_display_type']
                                        del self.cleaned_data['nationality_visa_passport_nationality']

    return cd_nvdf
```

Currently, the validated form highlights the above form fields, but for each form field on the template, the following html code is inserted into the html code, so that there is an extra line break under every form field:

```
<span class="help-inline">
    <strong>
        <br>
    </strong>
</span>
```

**How do I either, better write the validation code so that at least one form field is entered by the user and/or not include the extra line break code shown above?**

Comment: You could try and approach this problem from the javascript side. Before you send the ajax/form request, just require the user to have at least one of them filled.

Comment: @DannyBrown this does not work well for public APIs, you may need to limit the payload so that any malicious users do not take down your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the working solution:

```
    def clean(self):
    cd_nvdf = super(NationalityVisaDetailsForm, self).clean()

    if not any(
        cd_nvdf.get(x, '')
        for x in (
            'nationality_visa_country_of_birth',
            'nationality_visa_citizenship',
            'nationality_visa_residency',
            'nationality_visa_work_visa',
            'nationality_visa_study_visa',
            'nationality_visa_specialist_visa',
            'nationality_visa_other_visa',
            'nationality_visa_current_valid_passport_display_type',
            'nationality_visa_passport_nationality',
        )
    ):

        self._errors['nationality_visa_country_of_birth'] = self.error_class([_("You must enter at least one Nationality & Visa Detail.")])
        self._errors['nationality_visa_citizenship'] = self.error_class([_("You must enter at least one Nationality & Visa Detail.")])
        self._errors['nationality_visa_residency'] = self.error_class([_("You must enter at least one Nationality & Visa Detail.")])
        self._errors['nationality_visa_work_visa'] = self.error_class([_("You must enter at least one Nationality & Visa Detail.")])
        self._errors['nationality_visa_study_visa'] = self.error_class([_("You must enter at least one Nationality & Visa Detail.")])
        self._errors['nationality_visa_specialist_visa'] = self.error_class([_("You must enter at least one Nationality & Visa Detail.")])
        self._errors['nationality_visa_other_visa'] = self.error_class([_("You must enter at least one Nationality & Visa Detail.")])
        self._errors['nationality_visa_current_valid_passport_display_type'] = self.error_class([_("You must enter at least one Nationality & Visa Detail.")])
        self._errors['nationality_visa_passport_nationality'] = self.error_class([_("You must enter at least one Nationality & Visa Detail.")])

    return cd_nvdf
```

I hope that this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably some Django details that will assist you, but I would recommend considering the Python first.

For the first task, I think you could probably benefit from a `filter`.

First, we need a list of the values you want to check:

```
values_we_care_about = ['nationality_visa_country_of_birth'
                        'nationality_visa_citizenship'
                        'nationality_visa_residency'
                        'nationality_visa_work_visa',
                         etc.]
```

Next, we need to distill out the logic you're using to check stuff into a simple function

```
def checking_stuff_function(value_cared_about):
    return value_cared_about in cd_nvdf and cd_nvdf.get(value_cared_about, None)
```

Now, we can take this function and use it to filter *all* the values (if you're on Python2, this will return a list right away, but if you're on Python3, you'll get a generator; I'm going to assume Python2):

```
checked_values = filter(checking_stuff_function, values_we_care_about)
```

Now, we can check how many `checked_values` made it through. You can probably already see where this is going...

```
if len(checked_values) < 1:
   # There's an error!
```

Now, you just need to reset your form (and because we went with a filter before, why not go with a `map` here?):

```
map(lambda val: del self.cleaned_data[val], values_we_care_about]
```

I've never done that with a form, though. Is it really necessary to delete them on the overridden clean method? Can't this be handled better in the view? I'll leave that up to someone else to answer.

After that you can just return your form.

**EDIT**

I forgot about your errors. That can also be done in a manner similar to what we've done here and so I won't try to spell it out.

Pretty much what you're original code is missing is the DRY principle: 'don't repeat yourself.' Try to find common patterns in what you're doing and use those patterns to your advantage. If you're writing the same array of strings in three or four places, that's a problem. Save them to a list and iterate over them instead. Much less code to read.